# LinQ to get the latest group of records satisfying a condition

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have below stated 2 tables:

[image]

now I want to get the set of Child Table objects for whichever their parent table entries are latest(wr.r.t lastmodified). It should be something like....

```
List<Child_Table> List = ChildsList.Where(x=>x.name =="pqr" && status == "done")
    .Select(x=>x.Parent.lastmodified == recent record).....ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` on the date, then `OrderByDescending` on the `Key` then take the `First` followed by `SelectMany` to flatten the results.

```
var result = ChildsList.Where(x => x.name == "pqr" && x.status == "done")
     .GroupBy(x => x.Parent.lastmodified)
     .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
     .First()
     .SelectMany(g => g)
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes it worked for me Thanks. But only change is..instead of SelectMany(), we should use Select(). it solved my problem!!

Comment: @Nani If you don't do the `SelectMany` you'll end up with a `List<IGrouping<DateTime, Child_Table>>` instead of a `List<Child_Table>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join to accomplish it:

```
var results = children
    .Join(parents.OrderByDescending(p => p.lastmodified).Take(1),
        c => c.parent_id,
        p => p.id,
        (c, p) => c)
    .Where(x => x.name == "pqr" && x.status == "done")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @Nani I don't know why. I tested it with your exact data set and I get a list containing child record 4 returned.